# Getting runtime error on Stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, downtime

I just browsed to http://www.stackexchange.com and got an error page:

> [image]

Is this something wrong on my system or the server?

Comment: I get a down for maintenance message now. But I use FF and only accessed it about 15 minutes ago (and it worked) so guess it's a very temporary thing.

Comment: Probably just caching.

Comment: Uh oh!  A SE site is down!  Must race to meta to post a question about it!

Comment: It's a cache issue. Do a hard refresh... not on error page but http://stackexchange.com/

Comment: No this is not caching.

Answer (score 4):

We have reverted the build for stackexchange.com to a previous version while we investigate the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Still not working.